# Javascript using a Variable declared outside the function returns the value + undefined along with it

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

```
var name = "myName";

function test() {
    document.write(name);
}

var testcheck= test();

document.write(testcheck);
```

This returns  " myNameundefiend  " that is the value+undefined 
why is that happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning a value from your `test` function, making the `testcheck` variable `undefined`.

The `test()` call first writes the name to the document, then `document.write(testcheck);` adds `undefined` behind that.

You'll need to `return` `name` from the function:

```
function test() {
    document.write(name);
    return name;
}
```

There's no need to `document.write` twice. Either only keep it in the function, or remove it from the function and use `document.write(testcheck);`.